# What are the practical use differences between Flyweight vs Singleton patterns?

Tags: design-patterns

The two pattern seems to achieve the same thing. What are the different use cases in real world? 
Thanks

Comment: When I think of Singleton, I think of "global variable". When I think of Flyweight, I think of "pointer".

Comment: They are not achieving same thing.

Comment: What "thing" do you think they are to achieve? The patterns look quite different to me.

Comment: Both seem to be used to have only one instance of an object during an execution.

Comment: That is incorrect. Look up the flyweight pattern on Wikipedia, there can be any number of flyweight object. Often the flyweight pattern is used specifically because there will be extraordinarily many objects.

Comment: As I understood from the replies here, yes there can be many objects but they will all point to the same instance no? And in singleton one instance and one reference to it. Plus singleton is immutable.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A singleton is usually used to represent objects there is only one of, such as a keyboard, the computer screen, main memory. It could represent more abstract things like a messaging dispatch centre or coordinator. A database link for your whole application.

### Collection of Objects vs Single Objects

You could think of both a *Singleton* and a *Flyweight* as having a factory producing an object. A key difference is that the Singleton factory **always** returns the same object. A *Flyweight* factory in contrast is **parameterized**. The creation function takes an argument. Depending on the value of the argument a *different* Flyweight object will be returned.

You may have a singleton representing the current page being worked on in a word processor. The individual characters on the page however may be represented as *Flyweights*.

The similarity with a singleton here is that each occurrence of the character 'A' will refer to the same object. So giving 'A' as a parameter to the Flyweight factory will always return the same object. Hence there is a a singleton like behavior in that every time you create an 'A' object you get the same object returned.

The distinction from a *Singleton* factory is that the *Flyweight* factory allows a whole class of related objects to be created.

### Mutability

A *Singleton* is often mutable. However with Flyweights we tend to keep mutable state outside of the Flyweight. So e.g. if we have flyweight objects representing characters in a document, then the character position would typically be stored separate from the Flyweight object.

While I don't rule it out, I cannot think of any case where you would want to make the Flyweight object itself mutable. Imagine you have a Flyweight representing the character 'B' and then you change it to 'A'. Then 'B' in your document would change to 'A'. That would be highly undesirable.

Likewise if Flyweights represent color. It would confusing if you created a red color and it was green instead because its underlying flyweight object was changed to green somewhere else in the code.

### Examples

Examples from Cocoa (Objective-C):

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarHidden = YES
```

This is obviously a single object and you can change its state.

```
UIColor *red = [UIColor redColor]
```

In this case it is not obvious if we get a new object each time or not. Because colors are immutable, the maintainers of this API are free to implement common colors such as red, blue, green, yellow and gray as *Flyweight* objects. That means there is a pool of common objects which get reused when you call the constructor.

To the user it makes no difference whether a flyweight pattern is used behind the scenes or not. This is a reason why I will claim that immutability is a desirable property for flyweight objects.

Also note how *parameterization* is implicit in this case. You pick color, by using different named constructors. `yellowColor`, `blueColor` etc.

Comment: @Jayan How is mutability key?  I've seen and made lots of singletons that are immutable.  For example factories or property containers.  This is a good answer, and that may be a fair rule of thumb, but there are lots of reasons to use an immutable singleton.

Comment: If you read the explanation of flyweight on wikipedia, the description is very very different to what you describe here. IMO, they are completely unrelated. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

Comment: @PedroLoureiro My description is quite different, but I am not saying anything opposed to what wiki says. Rember I am not answering what a flyweight is. I am answering how they are different from singletons. So I chose a different angle than the wiki, emphasising different aspects.

Comment: Flyweights can be mutable, like singletons. So the difference has nothing to do with mutability.

Comment: @kmote I have updated my answer because it would be wrong to give the impression that mutability is the key difference. Flyweights are about collections of related objects. But immutability helps get this working properly.

Comment: @Maggyero I have updated my answer. Perhaps you can give examples of where mutable Flyweights are desirable? I think the sensible approach is to keep mutable state outside the flyweight object. Otherwise I would assume reuse would be difficult, defeating the purpose of Flyweights.

Comment: That is a great update Erik, thanks for taking my comment into account. "a whole class *or* related objects to be created" I guess you meant *of*. "Imagine you have a Flyweight representing the character 'B' and then you change it to 'A'." We would usually not change the part of the intrinsic state that contributed to the identification of the flyweight object, like the character code (e.g. ‘A’), but we could change the rest of the intrinsic state, like the character name (e.g. ‘Latin Capital letter A’ to ‘latin capital letter A’), its code units (e.g. ‘\x41’ in UTF-8 to ‘\x00\x41’ in UTF-16).

Answer (score 36):

Flyweight is when you have *many different kinds* of a single thing.

Singleton is when you have a single thing.

For example, you might use the Flyweight Pattern to represent keyboard characters.  One object for `a`, one for `b`, etc.  They are both characters, but different *kinds* of characters.

In contrast, you might use a singleton to represent the keyboard.  There can only be one.

Comment: i like that answer very much :)

Comment: very clear explanation

Comment: I created a public GitHub gist that demonstrates the Flyweight pattern with keyboard characters https://gist.github.com/timothyokooboh/55c9fde55bfc08274d690888ed2dc002

Answer (score 7):

They are unrelated:

Flyweight is reusing (obviously immutable) instances of a class wherever possible, rather than creating new instances of a class with the same "value", which saves CPU and memory.

Singleton is when there is only ever one instance of a (usually mutable) class. It is often used in multi-threaded environments to facilitate all threads using a single instance and "seeing" the same state.

Comment: Whoa, whoa, whoa. Saying "it is *often* used" and "it is used" are two totally different things.  There are lots of reasons besides threading to use a singleton.  For example, for some expensive operation that you only want performed once.

Comment: @TimPote Fine. "often" has been added.

Answer (score 3):

Flyweight is used when there is clear segregation of the object's intrinsic and extrinsic state exists. Intrinsic state can be shared across other extrinsic objects. For example a header of the documents can be classified as intrinsic state of the object and can be shared across. But rest of the data in the document may be very dynamic and filled by user(extrinsic data). To represent intrinsic data a flyweight object can be created and maintained inside flyweight factory. Flyweight factory object will serve as collection of flyweight(header objects)  and can be populated earlier and shared across various instances of the document in our case.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that singleton is a creational pattern, while flyweight is a structural pattern. Hence, the goal of the two patterns is completely different

Comment: Exactly.  Sorry, I didn't see this answer  when I posted mine but I expanded on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The flyweight *structual* pattern essentially removes duplication of objects needed to achieve a certain goal.  For example, imagine you were typing an essay (or maybe a post on stack overflow), which is ultimately comprised of the same 26 letters in the (English) alphabet, repeated many times.  Would it be more efficient to have 1000 separate objects each representing the letter 'E', or have one single object representing the letter 'E', referenced 1000 times?  (Hint, it would generally be the latter)

How the *creation* of each of the objects (ie. 26 letters) is implemented is a separate concern, however is commonly achieved with a factory method (a *creational* pattern) that utilizes "singleton like" characteristics.

- Initialize an empty collection of characters.
- Letter 'E' is needed?
- If it already exists, retrieve that object from the collection, otherwise create a new letter 'E' and store it in the collection, to be re-used the next time.

Is this done through a fully-fledged singleton object, or just a private variable that only the factory method can access?  May or may not be.  But either way, the singleton pattern is a *creational* pattern, describing ways to have only a single instance of an object in existence at any given point in time, and is not concerned with specific use cases such as "removing duplication of objects needed to achieve a certain goal".

Answer (score 0):

They are two entirely different "pattern **Types**".  Singleton is a "CREATION" pattern.  Creation patterns are higher order common "Object creation" methodologies. On the other hand, Flyweight is a "Structural pattern". Structural patterns have to do more with interfaces and implementation rather than "object creation".   Another easier way to describe the differences is the the first pattern type "Creation patterns" are more noun based.  The second "Structural pattern" types are more verb based.