# Singleton With Arguments

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, singleton

Is it a good idea having a Singleton that accepts an argument in its static constructor? Can I have concurrency problem?

```
public class DataHelper {
    private static DataHelper singleton = null;
    private Listener<Object> listener;

    public static DataHelper getInstance(Listener<Object> listener) {
        if(singleton == null) {
            singleton = new DataHelper();
        }
        singleton.listener = listener;

        return singleton;
    }
}
```

Comment: You would have concurrency problems even if there was no argument.

Comment: You should use a `Lock` on the constructor.  Additonally, design for multiple listeners (why not?) and use `ArrayList<MyListnerInterface>` with `addListener` and `removeListener` methods.

Comment: Singleton (design pattern) is not a good choice per se. Inject singletons using Dagger or RoboGuice.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! =) Should I have to manually manage synchronization during data access?

Comment: You may want to use `Flyweight pattern` instead of a singleton in your case i guess.

Comment: @nachokk Check this out.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750758/what-are-the-practical-use-differences-between-flyweight-vs-singleton-patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may not be bad (depending on your needs), it's definitely not a good idea. Since you already have a 'listener' object at the time of calling getInstance(), why not pass it as an argument to singleton's member functions? You have two race conditions in your function, one while creation of Singleton, and the other while setting 'listener' member variable. The second one could be avoided by not passing the argument at all. Even in a single threaded environment, you have a problem

```
void foo() {
  DataHelper dh = DataHelper.getInstance(listener1);
  bar();
  // dh.listener no longer points to listener1
}

void bar() {
  DataHelper dh = DataHelper.getInstance(listener2);
}
```

If it helps, you should read about Dependency Injection as well.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an argument to your Singleton will not introduce a race condition (unless you are passing a reference to a shared object). However this implementation has a race condition already. What protects against two threads invoking the method simultanously? singleton is unprotected.